# doesn't correctly write\delete symbols from TextField

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to write construction for button enable after 13 symbols are written. But my symbols in TextField won't delete/write. If I delete setState, I can correctly write/delete symbols but my button doesn't work. What I can do, for all correctly work?

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

```
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MobileNumberState();
}

class _MobileNumberState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _isDisable = false;
  var _phone = '+996';
  final String wayMainLogo = 'assets/images/test.svg';

........................

                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(47.0, 50, 47, 0),
                            child: TextField(
                              // autofocus: false,
                              onChanged: (textInField) {
                                if (textInField.length == 13) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _phone = textInField;
                                    _isDisable = true;
                                  });
                                } else if (textInField.length < 13) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _phone = textInField;
                                    _isDisable = false;
                                  });
                                }
                              },
                              controller: TextEditingController(
                                text: _phone,
                              ),
                              inputFormatters: [
                                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(13),
                              ],
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              maxLength: 13,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                  ),
                                  labelText: '+996 XXX YYY YYY',
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  )),
                            ))),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(47.0, 50, 47, 0),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: _isDisable ? () {} : null,
                              child: const Text('Далее'),
                            ))),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some changes like-

1. define TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
2. controller: textController,

Hope, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove text from the controller.

```
controller: TextEditingController(),
```